# How to use array fields in Django models?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I have a model class Client and it has different fields. As shown below:

```
class Client(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
   dob = models.SlugField(max_length = 100)
   CNIC = models.SlugField(max_length = 100)
   property_type = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
   down_payment = models.IntegerField()
   date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   installment_month = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
   installment_amount = models.IntegerField(null = True)
   installment_date = models.SlugField(max_length = 100)
```

I have different templates and views for first 6 fields (as these will be asked when adding a new client to the database),and the last 3 fields(installment_month, installment_amount, installment_date) because these fields will be used everytime when client pays an installment.

Now, when I try to add a new installment it asks me for these 3 fields but it replaces the values entered last time, because each of these 3 fields can only store 1 value.

Does anyone has an idea how can I declare array fields for these so that they can store all the installments, their months and their date?

Comment: It would make more meaningful if you added your views to the question that is where the saving logic is for the form submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this field need to be in another model like :

```
class Installment(models.Model):
   client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
   month = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
   amount = models.IntegerField(null = True)
   date = models.SlugField(max_length = 100)
// and other who need to be change
```

And you can rewrite your save methode for Client to link easy both model (not advise).

Comment: I added the new model class called Installment and add the respective fields. But when I enter the installment month, installment amount and click on button 'add installment', it gives the error `Operational Error at <the URL of add-installment>`and it says `no such table found: property_details_installment`. Note: Property_details is my app name